# Can CMake/CPack generate multiple NSIS installers for a single project?

Tags: windows, cmake, cpack

I have a single project (with sub-projects) for which I would like to generate multiple NSIS installer executables, instead of having multiple components listed in a single NSIS installer.  Is this possible?  Or do I need to organize my code into separate projects?

Comment: Do you want installer executables be per-subproject? If so, why not to build every subproject alone, with its installer? For make NSIS installer(and any other) to separate installed files you need to assign them to different *components*. `project()` command, which starts every sub-project, has no sence for CPack.

Answer (score 2):

One could provide a CMake attribute e.g. `COMPONENT` which can be set to a value from a predefined set of package names like: COMPONENT_1|COMPONENT_2|...COMPONENT_X

The package name could even be a name that does not correspond to a single component name but a set of components that would be added in the CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL. If the COMPONENT is equal to ALL_COMPONENTS then the value of CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL would contain all possible components.

The cmake packaging:

```
if (WIN32)
  set (CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL ${COMPONENT})
  set (CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME ${COMPONENT})
  set (CPACK_COMPONENT_${COMPONENT}_DISPLAY_NAME "${COMPONENT}")
  set (CPACK_COMPONENT_${COMPONENT}_DESCRIPTION "${COMPONENT}")  
  set (CPACK_NSIS_DISPLAY_NAME "${COMPONENT}")
  set (CPACK_NSIS_PACKAGE_NAME "${COMPONENT}")
  set (CPACK_NSIS_INSTALL_ROOT "C:")
  set (CPACK_GENERATOR NSIS)
else()
  ...
endif()
```

To create an installer for each COMPONENT you would run for example:

```
cmake -DCOMPONENT=COMPONENT_1 ../
nmake package
cmake -DCOMPONENT=COMPONENT_2 ../
nmake package
...
cmake -DCOMPONENT=COMPONENT_X ../
nmake package
```

Bear in mind that since the binaries are build on the first execution of `nmake package`, the subsequent calls to `cmake` and `nmake package` will only re-configure the packaging and only build the requested COMPONENT(aka COMPONENT)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I think there is a typo and the correct cmake sequence is `-DCOMPONENT=COMPONENT_1`