# How can I use CMake to generate multiple NSIS installers?

Tags: cmake, nsis

I have a project that uses CMake, which consists of a few executables, a few DLLs, and a number of small plugins, all of which are packaged into an NSIS installer. I now want to split off a small part of the project’s functionality into a stand-alone program. This program will have a new executable, which relies heavily on code from the larger project, but none of the rest.

I’ve set up my new stand-alone program, but I want to be able to use CMake to generate a separate NSIS installer containing only my stand-alone program. How can I use CMake to generate multiple NSIS installers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873339/can-cmake-cpack-generate-multiple-nsis-installers-for-a-single-project/44266815#44266815

Comment: apologies for the double post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can CMake/CPack generate multiple NSIS installers for a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873339/can-cmake-cpack-generate-multiple-nsis-installers-for-a-single-project)